# BufferedReader reading empty lines instead of newly added lines

Tags: java, bufferedreader, read-write

Im currently working on a application to manage a remote minecraft server and the first thing Im working on is observing the messages in the minecraft console. Im doing this by observing the latest.log textfile in which the minecraft server copies its output. The log messages are added each in a newline, so the basic workflow for monitoring is:

```
start -> read all existing lines of latest.log -> watch for file change notifications on latest.log -> 
read newly added line(s) -> wait for next file change notification
```

Ive implemented the following class to do this:

```
public class McServerService {
    
    
    
    private String directory;
    
    
    private List<String> currentLog;
        
    private Thread logObserverThread;
    private PropertyChangeSupport pcsupport;
    
    
    public McServerService (String directory) {
        this.currentLog = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.directory = directory;
        this.pcsupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }
    
    public void startWatching ()  {
        this.logObserverThread = new Thread(new LogObserverThreadImpl(this.directory));
        this.logObserverThread.start();
    }
    
    public void addNewLogLine (String newLogLine) {
        this.pcsupport.firePropertyChange("currentLog", this.currentLog, newLogLine);
        this.currentLog.add(newLogLine);
        System.out.println("addNewLogLine: " + newLogLine);
        
    }
    
    public void addPropertyChangeListener (PropertyChangeListener pcl) {
        this.pcsupport.addPropertyChangeListener(pcl);
    }
    
    public void removePropertyChangeListener (PropertyChangeListener pcl) {
        this.pcsupport.removePropertyChangeListener(pcl);
    }
    
    
        
    private class LogObserverThreadImpl implements Runnable {
        
        BufferedReader br;
        WatchService watchService;
        
        private LogObserverThreadImpl (String directory) {
            try {
                this.br = new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(directory + "\\" + "latest.log"));
                String nextLine = this.br.readLine();
                while (nextLine != null) {
                    McServerService.this.currentLog.add(nextLine);
                    System.out.println("init: " + nextLine);
                    this.br.mark(2048);
                    nextLine = this.br.readLine();
                    System.out.println("init: " + nextLine);
                }
                this.br.reset();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Path path = Paths.get(directory);
            try {
                System.out.println("entered try");
                this.watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
                path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
                WatchKey key;
                while ((key = this.watchService.take()) != null) {
                    for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                        if (event.context().toString().equals("latest.log")) {
                            String line = this.br.readLine();
                            /*
                             * if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("")) { line = this.br.readLine(); }
                             */
                            McServerService.this.addNewLogLine(line);
                            System.out.println("thread: " + line);
                        }
                    }
                    key.reset();
                }
                System.out.println("after while");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    

    
    
}
```

The existing latest.log textfile is read as exspected with all its lines and then ends on null, but when adding the two lines

```
gadhsjlhgadsjlkh
jlhkadshljhads
```

and saving the file after each line, the output looks like this:

```
init: null //"last" line of existing file
entered try
//now adding the two lines
pclimlp: 
addNewLogLine: 
thread: 
pclimlp: gadhsjlhgadsjlkh
addNewLogLine: gadhsjlhgadsjlkh
thread: gadhsjlhgadsjlkh
```

The problem is solved by uncommenting the equals check for "" in:

```
while ((key = this.watchService.take()) != null) {
                    for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                        if (event.context().toString().equals("latest.log")) {
                            String line = this.br.readLine();
                            /*
                             * if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("")) { line = this.br.readLine(); }
                             */
                            McServerService.this.addNewLogLine(line);
                            System.out.println("thread: " + line);
                        }
                    }
                    key.reset();
                }
```

But why is the BufferedReder reading empty lines there in the first place? Id understand null if the BufferedReader isnt updated yet, but why empty lines? Also if I manually save the file again (without adding more lines or anything), the BufferedReader will read the line it hasnt read before fine and is not skipping it. Can someone explain what happens there to cause this behaviour?

Comment: A little off-topic but: any reason to avoid simple ssh or the various rcon (remote console) options already integrated into the server?

Comment: @Rogue Fruther along the line this is going to be the foundation of a discordbot and website to manage the server. Im playing with a few friends, who are not all that into using ssh or rcon, so I want to build an easy to use solution to manage the server. Also there would be functionality integrated like editing the server.properties file amongst other things thats a bit more tedious with just ssh/rcon. And ultimately this seemed like a good project for me to just do some programming.

Comment: I wonder if this isn't a windows/linux thing?  https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2021/05/06/why-windows-and-linux-line-endings-dont-line-up-and-how-to-fix-it#:~:text=to%20line%20endings-,Back%20to%20line%20endings,on%20the%20other%2C%20hilarity%20ensues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BufferedReade.readLine() reads until either the next linefeed or the end of file.

So when reading this file:

```
[......]
[21:34:31] [Server thread/INFO]: [removed] left the game
```

BufferedReader gives the following output:

```
[......]
init: [21:34:31] [Server thread/INFO]: [removed] left the game
init: null
```

"init: " was only added for debug purposes.
When appending

```
xx
ghasjdkhajs
```

So the end of the file looks like this:

```
[21:34:31] [Server thread/INFO]: [removed] left the gamexx
ghasjdkhajs
```

This leads to the following output:

```
pclimlp: xx
addNewLogLine: xx
thread: xx
```

So BufferedReader was at the end of the file which was directly after

```
left the game
```

So when adding

```
xx\r\nghasjdkhajs
```

the BufferedReader reads until the next linefeed. If there wasnt the "xx" added there would simply be nothing before the next linefeed, so the BufferedReader would return "" like in the question.